# WPF TexBox does not get focus on mouse click if HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

In my WPF app, I have two TextBoxes with exactly same properties except HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" on one of them.

The first one, without HorizontalContentAlignment gets focus when you click with mouse anywhere in the textbox.

The second one, with HorizontalContentAlignment="Right", will receive focus only when mouse clicked on top of content, not on empty area. Infact, the TextBox bottom border does not even changes color on mouse hover on empty area.

I am using MaterialDesignTheme and this problem seems to be specific to it.

I am attaching two images to explain the situation. Any suggestions will be helpful.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You've obfuscated your area of `HitTestVisibility` by negating the ContentAlignment. Use `TextAlignment="Right"` instead.

Comment: Wow! Super easy. Thanks a lot @ChrisW.